Draw arabic symbols with FreeType
I'm doing text rendering with FreeType and OpenGL. I successfully draw english and cyrillic text. But gonna add support for arabic and chinese text.
Somehow arabic symbols are not recognized with unicode charset.
For example I use arabic symbol with code 0xFD9D:
FT_Library library;
FT_Face face;
FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
FT_New_Face(library, "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialbd.ttf", 0, &face);
FT_Select_Charmap(face, FT_ENCODING_UNICODE);
FT_Uint charIndex = FT_Get_Char_Index(face, 0xFD9D);

charIndex is 0, so FreeType renders rectangle instead of desired glyph. How do I draw it?

Does the font include the Arabic glyph? Try opening it in a font viewer application to find out. TTFs don't magically have every glyph that exists, many of them don't have much more than Latin.

Hm, for real, font doesn't include this glyph. According to description, its combination of other glyphs.
